# How can I provide an array as a file argument to a script, so that each element is like a line in a file?

Tags: bash, scripting, array, arguments

Suppose a bash script expects an argument to be a file. But we have a bash array, and would like to provide the array in some way as an argument to the script, as if there were a file whose lines are the elements of the array.  I wonder how to do that?

For a simple example, I have a script `myscrpt` containing a single command, which expects a file argument

```
cat $1
```

and I have an array

```
arr=( 1 3 5 )
```

and how can I provide `arr` as an argument to the script, as if the argument is actually a file whose content is

```
1
3
5
```

does  `myscript <(echo "${arr[@]}")` work?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe with words what the combination of your two scripts is doing?  It looks like it could be done in a much more efficient way...

Comment: Thanks. See my update. I guess `comm` may solve my ultimate problem (but needs `sort` on the file arguments, which change the line order, undesirably). But right now I just wonder if a script is expecting a file argument, how can I provide an array to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `bash` or some other array-capable shell you can use a `"${var[@]}"` type construct.

```
a=(one two 'three four' five)
printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"
```

Pipe the `printf` into whatever expects elements one per line, for example

```
printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" | myscript
```

It's really important to double-quote the array expansion; otherwise the `@` character is treated as `*` and the array expansion gets (wrongly) treated to word splitting on whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have your script (only a bit modified to add `#!`-line and quotes around the expansion of `$1` as to support reading from files with unusual filenames),

```
#!/bin/sh
cat "$1"
```

Now you want to call this script with an array

```
arr=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
```

so that instead of reading a file (which your script is doing), it reads newline-delimited value from you array, producing

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

as output?

This is how this may be done:

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | ./script -
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | ./script /dev/stdin
```

This would pass `-` or `/dev/stdin` to your script as the file to read from. The `cat` will interpret `-` as standard input, and if given `/dev/stdin` will likewise read from standard input.

The data is provided on standard input by `printf` which provides it as newline-delimited elements from the array.

The same effect would be had with

```
( IFS=$'\n'; sh ./script.sh - <<<"${arr[*]}" )
```

where the data is provided via a here-string.  By using `"${arr[*]}"`, we join the elements of the array into a single string separated by the first character of `$IFS` (which we set to a newline). I'm using a subshell here to avoid modifying `IFS` in the surrounding environment.